# Laravel - Post Policy Didn't Redirect Back to Post Index

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, web

I am studying web with laravel framework. I have a problem for creating authorization policies.

the problem is i cannot redirect back to post.index using Create, and didn't save in phpMyAdmin. Edit, Update, and Delete function are worked.

This is my code:

**PostController.php**

```
    public function create(){
        return view ('admin.posts.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        $inputs = request()->validate([
            'title'=>'required|min:8|max:255',
            'post_image'=>'file', //mime: jpeg, png
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
        if(request('post_image')){
            $inputs['post_image'] = request('post_image')->store('images');
        }
        auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
        session()->flash('post-create-message', 'Post was Created ' . $inputs['title']);
        // return back();
        return redirect()->route('post.index');
    }
```

and this **PostPolicy.php:**

```
public function create(User $user)
    {            
        return $user->is($user);
    }
```

Comment: if it is not redirecting then it is validation error

Comment: can you provide me with more detail, please?.... after successing login and trying to create a post, it did nothing and didn't give me any error

Comment: you are submiting form then .?

Comment: yes, i tried to submitting new Post but didn't save it... it didn't give me any error either... while read, edit, and delete function in Post are worked.

Comment: Try again with `'post_image'=>'sometimes|file'`, your validation needs a file as it stands now. No uploaded file = fail. Unless that's what you want;

Comment: when would `$user` not be `$user` ?

Answer (score 0):

inside your from put this is validatio error which you can check by this code

```php
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="error">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```